# How can I read a xls in shiny? R-Studio

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I'm working with shiny because I want to do a dashboard but when I do a plot appear a some error. I would like to read the database from a file in my own pc.

I don't want this https://jamesmccammon.com/2014/12/29/shiny-web-app/

````
#ui

library(shinydashboard)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(

  hr(),

    sidebarMenu(id="tabs",
                menuItem("a", tabName="a", icon=icon("pagelines"), selected=TRUE),
                menuItem("b", icon=icon("chart-bar"),
                menuItem("c", tabName = "c", icon=icon("chart-bar")),
                menuItem("d", tabName = "d", icon = icon("chart-bar")),
                menuItem("e", tabName = "e", icon=icon("mortar-board")),
                menuItem("f", tabName = "f", icon = icon("question"))
                ),width = 285
                          )

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "a",
            withMathJax(), 
            includeMarkdown("principal.Rmd")
    ),

    tabItem(tabName = b",
            dateRangeInput('b_fecha',
                           label = 'Por favor seleccionar fecha:',
                           start = Sys.Date() - 2, end = Sys.Date() + 2, format = "mm yyyy", startview = 'year', language = 'es'
                          ), 

            column(width = 8,
                   box(  width = NULL, plotOutput(outputId = "b_iden_grap"), collapsible = TRUE,
                         title = "Plot", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE)
                  )
            )
          ))



dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "title", titleWidth=285),
  sidebar,
  body
)

# server

library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(zoo)


shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  df1.1.1=data.frame(read_excel("C:/Users/.../Base.xlsx", sheet = "1.1.1"))
  df1.1.1$mes.y.año = as.yearmon(as.Date(df1.1.1$mes.y.año, origin="1899-12-30"))

  output$admision_iden_grap <- renderPlot({


    plot(df1.1.1$mes.y.año, (1-(df1.1.1$errores/df1.1.1$egresos))*100,  ylim= c(0,100), type ="h")

  })

})```
````

> shiny::runApp('C:/.../...') Loading required package: shiny
>        Listening on http://###.#.#.#:####
>        Attaching package: ‘shinydashboard’
>        The following object is masked from ‘package:graphics’:
>        box
>        Warning in checkEncoding(file) :
>         The input file C:...\Prueba/server.R does not seem to be encoded in UTF8 Warning in readLines(file, warn = FALSE) :
>         invalid input found on input connection 'C:.../server.R' Error in parse(file, keep.source = FALSE, srcfile = src, encoding = enc) : 
>         C:.../server.R:11:0: unexpected end of input
>       9:   df1.1.1=data.frame(read_excel("C:/Users/.../Base.xlsx", sheet = "1.1.1"))
>       10:   df1.1.1$mes.y.a
>          ^ Warning: Error in sourceUTF8: Error sourcing C:...\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpwbMkRB\file42c486c4a65
>         [No stack trace available] Error in sourceUTF8(serverR, envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())) :  Error sourcing
>   C:...\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpwbMkRB\file42c486c4a65

Comment: Looks like your special characters cause the problem (the "n" with the tilde). I would try to save the file in UTF8 encoding (in RStudio: File -> Save with encoding), or to remove these special characters.

Comment: You're propably missing `"` in `tabName = b"`

Comment: @Stéphane-Laurent you're right! it was that, thks!

Comment: Ok, so I convert to an answer.

Comment: @ JRN, If my answer solves your problem, then please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Otherwise the question is considered as non-answered by the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to the special characters like `ñ`.

As you can see in the warning message:

> The input file C:...\Prueba/server.R does not seem to be encoded in
>   UTF8

So save your files in UTF8 encoding. To do so in RStudio, do `File -> Save with encoding` (if that still doesn't work, remove the special characters).